# RabbitMQ + Reactor, sending ACK after passing on message?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, project-reactor, reactor-rabbitmq

I'm trying to figure out if Project-Reactor is a viable option for my use case.

I need high consistency in my application, I want to:

1. Receive a message from RabbitMQ
2. Do some manipulation/transformation
3. Put the message on a (different) RabbitMQ queue
4. Send an ACK for the original message

With the normal RabbitMQ Java library it would roughly look something like this:

```
var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
var connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();
var channel = connection.createChannel();
channel.txSelect();
channel.queueDeclare("queue.A", true, false, false, null);
channel.queueDeclare("queue.B", true, false, false, null);

channel.basicConsume("queue.A", false, (tag, delivery) ->
{
    String data = new String(delivery.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println("Received: " + data);
    channel.basicPublish("", "queue.B", null, data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    channel.txCommit();
    System.out.println("Sending ACK");
    channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
    channel.txCommit();

}, tag -> System.err.println("Tag " + tag + " failed"));
```

This nicely prints

```
Received: DATA
Sending ACK
```

Using Reactor-RabbitMQ I've come up with the following:

```
var options = new ReceiverOptions();
var receiver = RabbitFlux.createReceiver(options);
var sender = RabbitFlux.createSender();
sender.declare(QueueSpecification.queue("queue.A")).block();
sender.declare(QueueSpecification.queue("queue.B")).block();
sender
    .send(receiver.consumeManualAck("queue.A")
        .doOnError(ex -> ex.printStackTrace())
        .doOnEach(s ->
        {
            s.get().ack();
            print("ACK");
        })
        .map(ad ->
        {
            print("MAP");
            return new OutboundMessage("", "queue.B", ad.getBody());
        }))
    .doOnEach(v ->
    {
        print("SUB");
    })
    .subscribe();
```

However, this prints

```
ACK
MAP
```

Which is not the right order, obviously, because I'm doing the `doOnEach` before `map`. But the `AcknowledgableDelivery` is no longer available after I've mapped it to `OutboundMessage` for the sender.

note that `SUB` is never printed. Probably because the `send` subscription is continuous and never reaches the `Mono<Void>` terminated state.

My knowledge of Reactor is not that extensive, so I feel like I'm missing something I could use here. Is it possible to do this neatly with Reactor or should I forget about it?

---

*<sub>Footnote: I'm using `var` because I'm in Java 11, and the print statements as a way to quantify the order in which things are executed.</sub>*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to acknowledge inside send method. Instead you can try:

```
receiver.consumeManualAck("queue.A")
        .flatMap(ad -> {
           Mono<OutboundMessage> outboundMessageMono =
                Mono.just(new OutboundMessage("", "queue.B", ad.getBody()));
           return sender.send(outboundMessageMono)
                        .doFinally(signalType -> {
                            if (signalType == SignalType.ON_COMPLETE) {
                               ad.ack();
                            } else {
                               ad.nack(false);
                           }
                         });
         });
```